# Cast query string to Query or SelectQuery object using jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have some query string:

```
String queryStr = "SELECT * FROM car";
```

I want cast this object to SelectQuery and then use incremental query building.

How to cast String object into SelectQuery?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot *cast* a `String` to any Java object. You can either:

#### Translate the SQL string to a jOOQ query

With jOOQ's DSL API, you'd be writing something like:

```
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select()
   .from(CAR);
```

With jOOQ's Model API (i.e. to produce a `SelectQuery`), you'd be writing something like:

```
SelectQuery select = DSL.using(configuration).selectQuery();
select.addFrom(CAR);
```

You're looking for the latter. [The two APIs are compared here, in the manual](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/dsl-and-non-dsl/)

#### Embed the SQL string in a jOOQ query

This is not what you're looking for, but for completeness's sake, you can also embed SQL strings directly into jOOQ objects, e.g.

```
ResultQuery<?> query = DSL.using(configuration).resultQuery("SELECT * FROM car");
```